# Fortran 95 Special Program Just Reading and Writing

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran95

I try to write a program with fortran 95 that will read a file. This file is created after a calculation by a software. After reading related information from this file I want to write another text file. I have a file like this;

```
 Model_disp

 Analysis type         NONLIN
 Step nr.              10    
 Load factor           1.000E+00 
 Result                DISPLA TOTAL  TRANSL
 Axes                  GLOBAL

 Nodnr       TDtX       TDtY       TDtZ  
   301   -7.359E-03 -7.205E-02  2.207E-02



 Analysis type         NONLIN
 Step nr.              27    
 Time                  3.400E-02 
 Result                DISPLA TOTAL  TRANSL
 Axes                  GLOBAL

 Nodnr       TDtX       TDtY       TDtZ  
   301   -7.356E-03 -7.202E-02  2.207E-02



 Analysis type         NONLIN
 Step nr.              44    
 Time                  6.800E-02 
 Result                DISPLA TOTAL  TRANSL
 Axes                  GLOBAL

 Nodnr       TDtX       TDtY       TDtZ  
   301   -7.362E-03 -7.202E-02  2.209E-02
..............
..............
..............

 Analysis type         NONLIN
 Step nr.              17010    
 Time                  3.400E+01 
 Result                DISPLA TOTAL  TRANSL
 Axes                  GLOBAL

 Nodnr       TDtX       TDtY       TDtZ  
   301   -2.726E-01 -6.948E+00  3.902E+00
```

I want to read Time, TDtx and TDtz after that I want to write these parameters to another .txt file. This file has totaly 11014 line.

The program that I want to write with fortran is that;

```
PROGRAM reading
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL :: Time, TDtx, TDtz


OPEN(1, FILE='Model_disp.txt', &
        STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ'

READ(1,*), Time, TDtx, TDtz
PRINT*, Time, TDtx, TDtz

OPEN(2, FILE='disp.txt', STATUS='NEW', ACTION='WRITE')
  WRITE(2,*), Time, TDtx, TDtz

END PROGRAM
```

Unfortunately, I failed. I do not know where is my mistake.
Would you like to help me?

Comment: I'd like to help you but (i) the format of the code in your question doesn't make it easy to read and (b) you don't tell us how you failed. Help us to help you.

Comment: Further to High Performance Mark's (b), I'll guess that you want to do some parsing of the file.  Basic `read`s won't do that.

Comment: To extend fraacescalus comment, you will have to identify where in the file the values you want are.   It might be as simple as skipping a fixed number of lines, reading the values, and repeat.  If there are variations, you might have to read each line from the file into a string and check whether you have read the relevant line, and if so, read the values from the string.

Comment: Actually when I try to compile program gives a warning like;

Comment: \read.F95(6) : warning 868 - Opening unit 1 may affect the operation of input from the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
\read.F95(7) : error 573 - Missing expression
\read.F95(7) : error 52 - Compilation abandoned

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to read input file in a given format, extract something and write the it in another text file, the script languages ([Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), Perl or so) would better suite your needs.

Comment: It strongly depends on the data format and what you want to do with it. I do post processing in Fortran very often and I know Python and use when it is appropriate. Fortran library for regular expressions could be a solution sometimes.

Comment: Fortran is the only program that I know, that is why I try to write a program with fortran to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to parse the file you need to do a little more than your `read` statements.  Making the assumptions that:

- On a line starting "Time" there is your variable `time`;
- On a line after one starting "Nodnr" are your variables `TDtx` and `TDtx`;
- Lines are suitably ordered.

you can do something like (with the appropriate declarations, `open`s etc.):

```
do
  read(unit_in, '(A)', iostat=iostat) line
  if (iostat.ne.0) exit
  if (line(1:4).eq.'Time') then
    read (line(5:), fmt1) time
    cycle
  end if
  if (line(1:5).eq.'Nodnr') then
    read (unit_in, fmt2) junk1, tdtx, junk2, tdtz
    write (unit_out, *) time, tdtx, tdtz
  end if
end do
```

where `fmt1` and `fmt2` are desired formats.

The example file suggests "Nodnr" comes first, if so, that can be handled with the appropriate changes; I've assumed from your example code that `time` would be read first.

Of course, there is plenty more to do here such as checking conditions.  Depending on your exact case you may be able to make this simpler, or it may need to be much more general.

Finally, if you are just doing text processing and the input file is very unreliable other tools may be better (but not required).